# Cocoa sqlite db file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sqlite

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding why the below code is not working:

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement5;

NSString *databasePath2 = @"default-gameData.db";
NSInteger speed_int = 0;

const char *dbPath2 = [databasePath2 UTF8String];

if(sqlite3_open(dbPath2, &db)==SQLITE_OK){
    NSString *getspeeds = @"SELECT * FROM planeInfo";
    NSLog(@"%@",getspeeds);
    const char *getspeed_stmt = [getspeeds UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, getspeed_stmt, -1, &statement5, nil)==SQLITE_OK){

        NSLog(@"%d",sqlite3_step(statement5));

        NSString *org_plane_info_id = [[NSString alloc] init];

        while(sqlite3_step(statement5) == SQLITE_ROW){
            if((const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement5, 1)==NULL){
                org_plane_info_id = @"no";
            }
            else{
                org_plane_info_id = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement5, 1)];
            }
            NSLog(@"%@",org_plane_info_id);
            if(org_plane_info_id==plane_info_id){
                NSString *speed = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement5, 2)];
                NSLog(@"%@",speed);
                speed_int = [speed integerValue];

                return speed_int;
            }
        }
    }
}
if(speed_int==0){
    return 0;
}
sqlite3_close(db);
```

I've found the source of the problem being the database path, the file is stored where the .h and .m files are so I think that's where I am going wrong, but what do I have to do to get that to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocoa/Foundation doesn't know where your file is. You need to tell it that it's in the app bundle.

```
NSString *databasePath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"default-gameData" ofType:@"db"];
```

Comment: hmmmm, this still isn't working, when I select a different file somewhere else it works, but it still doesn't work with the file stored locally...

Comment: also if you are copying in the DB file make sure it is listed in Copy Bundle Resources under Build Phases

Comment: @Lenny So is the file there, actually? Is it in the app bundle?

Comment: yep that was the problem, I'm just learning this all and i had no chance against that :P, thanks both of you, helped me a lot :)

Comment: @H2CO3 owen solved the rest, I#ll mark your answer correct as soon as the timers done :)